# Does LTspice peak current for inductors do anything?

Tags: inductor, ltspice

LTSpice has a "peak current" parameter for inductors, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Setting it to near zero or some huge value has no effect. One would expect it to be the saturation current, but it's not. What is that parameter for?

Answer (score 3):

From experimenting, setting a value here adds "Ipk=*value*" to the inductor's card in the netlist. However nothing in the help files documents any meaning for this parameter.

According to [this brief thread](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/LTspice/conversations/topics/64551) on the LTSpice mailing list, the peak current parameter does not affect the simulation and is only provided as a reference for the user.

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/power-electronics-capstone/lecture/JFPHu/the-ltspice-saturating-inductor-model

Comment: @G36, yes LTSpice has a saturating inductor model. But Ipk is not one of the parameters that adjust that model and putting a value in the peak current field on the graphical schematic capture will not lead it to use that model.